# I am finding an email from from a given string and returning the email that exists in the string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

**My requirements are-**

**name**: the name is an alphanumeric string that is less than or
equal to 12 characters. Additional characters allowed are
dash (-), period (.) and underscore (_). But the email
cannot start or end with these additional characters.
The name must also be at least 1 character long.
Example name values:
**a,
ab,
a_b,
A__B..C--D,
1nt3r3st.1ng**

**domain**: the domain is strictly numerical, and the number must be
divisible by 5. the length of the domain is unrestricted.
Example domain values:
**984125,
0**

**ending**: the email must end with a (.com) or (.ca) (case sensitive)

**Exmaple:**

```
find_special_email('12345a_test_email@165265365.com!')

'a_test_email@165265365.com'
```

**What I have tried:**

```
import re

def find_special_email(str):
   match = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]{1,12}@[0-9]+\.(com|ca)(\.[a-z]{2,3})?', str)
   return match.group(0)


print(find_special_email('12345a_test_email@165265365.com!'))
print(find_special_email('A__B..C--D@165265365.com!'))
```

**My Issues:**

> 1. the email cannot start or end with these additional characters e.g  dash (-), period (.) and underscore (_)
> 2. I don't know how to match the "domain" that is divisible by 5

Comment: Regex isn't much good with numbers but this particular numeric requirement can be rephrased as "ends with 0 or 5".

Comment: Domain names by definition are not case sensitive.

Comment: Your "exmaple" is weird. Why would you want to extract a partial address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex - https://regex101.com/r/wSS0ES/4 can help.

**Regex:** `[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,10}[a-zA-Z0-9])?@[0-9]*[05]+\.(?:com|ca)(?:\.[a-z]{2,3})?`

**Changes Made:**

1. Prefixed `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so that email starts with a valid character.
2. `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{0,10}[a-zA-Z0-9])?` - after the first char, the address can optionally contain 0 to 10 times of all valid chars in the middle, but should end with an alphanumeric char. The entire expression is made optional so that it can match a single valid char in the address part.
3. `[0-9]*[05]+` - it ensures domain can contain multiple numbers but it should end with 0 or 5